# How do I access methods/attributes of one object to use in another object in Python?

Tags: python, function, oop, scipy, bisection

I have two objects below:

```py
class foo1:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def calc(self):
        return self.value**2

class foo2:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def calc(self):
        return self.value**3
```

I am planning on doing a bisection method function (whether using scipy.optimize or not). However, the function I need to evaluate the bisection method on is `foo1.calc(value) - foo2.calc(value) = 0`.

I am relatively new to Python/OOP - is there a way to access these methods in a function/object, i.e. to do something equivalent to:

```py
def func(value):
    return foo1.calc(value) - foo2.calc(value)
```

I have considered using multi-class inheritance of `foo1` and `foo2` but I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: The first parameter to methods should normally be `self`. And you need to create objects from the classes. It sounds like you need to read a tutorial on Python OOP, you don't even know enough to ask a proper question.

Comment: Do you actually need two classes, or do you just need `calc1(value) and calc2(value)`?

Comment: Sorry I was in a rush. Updated it. I do need two classes since I do a lot of other things with each object. In this case specifically, I need calc1(value) and calc2(value) but the calculation itself is dependent on the object (each object has different formulas). @below -> I do need to instantiate it I apologize. I added the constructors

Comment: If you are not going to make instances of those classes you should just use a *normal* function. If you want to group similar functions together in a container, using a separate module (instead of a class) is the typical Python *way*.

Comment: You don't *have* to use inheritance, composition is always an option. But, it would also look like these two classes could just be the same class. Which way to go depends on the specifics of your situation, and these sort of toy examples aren't much to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use classes like this:

```
f1 = foo1(10)
f2 = foo2(3)
result = f1.calc() - f2.calc()
```

Comment: I guess I really oversimplified a lot of what I was intending by the question. I was trying to avoid having the actual script in main(). It seems from the constraints I have, my current code design requires me to just execute the root finding problem in main() and not be able to define it in a separate module.